# Django: NoReverseMatch at / --> Reverse for 'name' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$name/']

Tags: python, django, reverse

http://127.0.0.1:8000/ i get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'name' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$name/']

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.7.5
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    Reverse for 'name' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$name/']

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 468
```

---

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mydjapp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^name/', views.name, name='name'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html')

def name(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html')
```

templates/polls/index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="{% url 'name' %}">Hello</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dollar sign from the inclusion url:

```
url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
```